# C++ Multithreading in MFC Dialog Errors

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

i tried to implement multi threading following the example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mfc/mfc_multithreading.htm in this link.

```
UINT CCheckDlg::MyThreadProc(LPVOID Param) {
    while (1){
        Sleep(50); // would do some work here
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

this is called by using

```
AfxBeginThread(MyThreadProc, 0);
```

the following errors appears

1. E0304    no instance of overloaded function "AfxBeginThread" matches the argument list
2. C3867    'CCheckDlg::MyThreadProc': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Comment: I tried using both the changes, new error of    
"Error C2665 'AfxBeginThread': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types"   occurs now. i am using VS2019 in windows.

Comment: Try declaring your thread proc as `__cdecl` as described here: [AfxBeginThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-information-and-management?view=vs-2019#afxbeginthread) and here: [The __cdecl function specifier (C++ only)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbclx01/cdeclkey.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your call to `AfxBeginThread`. First, as pointed out in the comments, you need to ensure that your `CCheckDlg::MyThreadProc` is a `static` member function (which **must** have the `__cdecl` attribute, although this *may* be the default), and use `&CCheckDlg::MyThreadProc` as the first argument.

The other problem is that the `0` (second argument) is being interpreted as an `int` parameter, and thus the compiler cannot resolve which of the two overloads to select. Use `nullptr` - or an explicit `(void *)(0)` - as the second argument, so that the first overload will be selected.

The [two overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-information-and-management?view=vs-2019#afxbeginthread) for `AfxBeginThread` are:

```cpp
CWinThread* AfxBeginThread(
    AFX_THREADPROC pfnThreadProc,
    LPVOID pParam,
    int nPriority = THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
    UINT nStackSize = 0,
    DWORD dwCreateFlags = 0,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttrs = NULL);

CWinThread* AfxBeginThread(
    CRuntimeClass* pThreadClass,
    int nPriority = THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
    UINT nStackSize = 0,
    DWORD dwCreateFlags = 0,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttrs = NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thread proc must be `Global` function or a `Satic` member function of Class.

Please check whether the function *`CCheckDlg::MyThreadProc`* was defined static or not.

***There is a problem in your code as well.***

Even though TRUE is evaluated as UINT, this is a problem.
Of course it couldn't occur any error. But in general, all Threads returned 0 value when they were terminated successfully, if not they return -1.
Maybe TRUE is defined as -1. This means that your thread function always would be terminated as failed.

Comment: A thread can return *any* value to signal success or failure. There is no rule that any given value has any semantics assigned to it. There isn't even a convention. It's wildly unclear what *"would be terminated as failed"* is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you must do:

```
UINT CMFCDlg::MyThreadProc(LPVOID Param) {

    return 1;
}


UINT MyThreadProc(LPVOID pParam)
{  
    return 0;
}


BOOL CMFCDlg::CallingFunction()
{
    // First version 
    CWinThread * pThread = AfxBeginThread(MyThreadProc, 0);

    // Second version 
    pThread = AfxBeginThread(&CMFCDlg::MyThreadProc, 0);

    // third version 
    pThread = AfxBeginThread(MyThreadProc, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED);

    //fourth version
    pThread = AfxBeginThread(&CMFCDlg::MyThreadProc, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Knowing that the function has been declared as a continuation in the class:

```
UINT static MyThreadProc(LPVOID Param);
```

So you have two alternatives: either a global function, or a static function